# Is it correct, that i am able to change AngularJSs $scope variables through Google Chromes Developer Console?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, google-chrome, debugging

I have written a small AngularJS application. I am using the variable:

```
$scope.IsAdmin = boolean
```

What my colleague found out is, that we are able to open Google Chromes Developer Console and step into the JS code through the Debugger to look at the code and then for example do the following on the console:

```
$scope.IsAdmin = true;
```

After that the variable was modified and he could do whatever he wanted in the app.

Is this a general of AngularJS? What are you doing in real world apps to prevent from editing $scope variables?

br
Yavuz

Comment: It's all client side, so of course someone who knows javascript well enough along with the console can do whatever they want in your app. The REAL security comes in your backend preventing them from doing certain things regardless of what the front end sends to it.

Comment: Ah ok. That means, that i have to double check the privileges of the user and not only trust the fontend. For example when a users unhides a button to delete a record but has normally not the permission to do this, i need to check in the backend (e.g. wcf service) if the user has the permission to do this!?

Comment: Yes exactly, the front end is just 'dumb' it should not be your final point of security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide things and make it more difficult for the user to access the data but a user will always be able to access that data if they are dedicated enough. The key is to do server-side validation on all requests to confirm the user is who they say they are. This will keep the user from doing anything with their fake admin privileges.

Answer (score 4):

Javascript single page apps are never secure. Every data going out of the client should be verified by the server. No matter how much you'll uglify, there's always a tool that can pretyify the code back.

In regard to your problem - Angular is giving the ability to change scope properties directly for debugging during development.

If you want to block the debugging options do this:

```
angular.module('appModule', ['dependencies']
    .config(['$compileProvider', function($compileProvider) {
        $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);

    }]);
```

The [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider) say this about `debugInfoEnabled`:

> Call this method to enable/disable various debug runtime information
>   in the compiler such as adding binding information and a reference to
>   the current scope on to DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we do bundling and minifying to prevent debugging and changing variables by end users in production. It is a best practice which also aims reducing the size of assets and decreases page load time. You can read e.g. those blog posts:

https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2015/01/10/bundling-and-minification-an-introduction
 https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2015/02/22/bundling-and-minifying-an-angularjs-application-with-asp-net-mvc